# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

This error is coming while using datetimepicker in emberjs.

Here's my code

javascript code:-

```
App.DateTimePicker = Ember.TextField.extend ({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().datetimepicker();
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().datetimepicker('destroy');
  }
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-append date">
    {{view App.DateTimePicker data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" placeholder="End Date &        Time" valueBinding="endTime"}}
    <span class="add-on">
      <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I don't know where is the actual problem.

Please help me in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add some code with the order of js files referred and a call to the method which gives exception

Comment: I have added my code,now can anybody help me

Answer (score 3):

`datetimepicker` depends on both `twitter-bootstrap` and `moment.js`.  Both of those libraries need to be included in order for it to work.  Additionally the html that you are trying to attach the calendar to should be using the following html:

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a starter example using a component:

I haven't hooked up the bindings, but it should give you a start: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/moludemo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for ur help. :).I can proceed further now.

Comment: Come on dude, this is the second time, we don't want to have to pry to figure out what you mean when you say something's wrong.  If you have an issue state the exact problem, what you've tried, error messages, and what exactly isn't working.  I included an example that looks to be mostly working, so please be exact in stating what isn't working.